# Finding the Lengths of Two unknown squares

Tags: geometry

Four squares are all having their bases along a horizontal line, and their north-west corners are all lying on another line. Knowing the smaller squares have sides of lengths 7 and 8, respectively, find the side lengths of the larger squares. [image]

I have a previous problem with triangles instead of squares where we looked for similar triangles surrounding the given triangles. I am guessing that the right triangles above the squares with the hypotenuse on the horizontal line should somehow by similar? Since they each have a right angle and corresponding angles. I am having trouble with this question for some reason.

Comment: Hint: Take the first two right triangles. To deduce that they are similar, look for parallel lines, and then recall that corresponding angles formed by a transversal through two parallel lines are equal. That clinches similarity. Then apply the known side ratios to the other similar triangles.

Comment: if i take the first two right triangles and conduct they are similar, that means that $\frac{7}{8}$ $=$ ... that is where i think i am getting stuck @quasi

Comment: Each tr\iangle is 8/7 times the previous, for any corresponding sides.

Comment: i was actually able to figure this problem out after a while using pythagorean theorem and the fact that the triangles are congruent. @quasi

Answer (score 1):

The triangles above the individual squares and below the line connecting their northwest corners are similar right triangles. Since we know that the height to base ratio of the first triangle is one to seven, we know that the height to base ratio of each triangle is one to seven. Therefore to obtain the height of a square one must add one seventh the height of the previous square to the height of the previous square. Arithmetically, this is equivalent to multiplying the height of each square by $\frac{8}{7}$ to obtain the height of the next square. Thus the heights of the squares increase in a geometric progression with common ratio $\frac{8}{7}$.

To get the height $s_2=8$ of the second square from the first square $s_1=7$, one adds one-seventh the height of the first square to the first square. So the second square is $\frac{8}{7}$ the height of the first.

To get the height $s_3$ of the third square one adds one-seventh the height $s_2=8$ of the second square to the height of the second square

$$s_3=8+\frac{1}{7}\cdot8=\frac{64}{7}=\frac{8^2}{7}$$

To get the height $s_4$ of the fourth square one adds one-seventh the height of the third square to the height of the third square.

$$ s_4=\frac{64}{7}+ \frac{1}{7}\cdot\frac{64}{7}=\frac{512}{49}=\frac{8^3}{7^2}$$

The sides increase in geometric progression with $r=\frac{8}{7}$.

Comment: where did you get 6? the smallest square on the left has a side length of 7, and the second square has a side length of 8.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem. Will correct.

Comment: i am trying to do the problem by using similar triangles to use the ratio of their sides, since this is how we did it in class...could you direct me as to how to approach is that way? i seem to be having trouble with the ratios

Comment: It is because of the similar triangles that one always adds one-seventh the height of one square to obtain the height of the next. I will add that to my answer.